# Displaying variables as text in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm new to mobile development and I am having trouble displaying variables as text on to the screen.

```
public class wifiinfo() {
    public string getmac = getBSSID();
}
```

I have this in my main (blank) activity but I have no clue as to how to code this in with XML. The Android Developer tutorials haven't really helped me. Do I have to index the string in a database, perhaps? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TextView.setText(getmac) add this line to your code

Comment: @CyanidePlague what about this code what kind of this code you have to add some more details of your code

Comment: @amitsharma 'public class checker extends AppCompatActivity {

    (at symbol)Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checker);
    }
}
' This is the main activity and the code posted above is in a second .java file

Comment: code you have to add in asked question no need here to add in comment your code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Textview to display text.

Add this in your XML:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textViewSSID"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:hint="Your SSID"/>
```

And display text in activity like this:

```
TextView tvSSID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSSID);
String ssid = getBSSID();

tvSSID.setText(ssid);
```

Why you create an inner class to keep the value of ssid is a real mystery to me. You can make the variable getmac as a member variable in the activity and initialize it in your onCreate of your activity.

Update:

As to your comment, your activity should start somewhat like this:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {

   private string MacId = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        MacId = getBSSID();

       //Other functions
    }
```

Comment: So is the entire wifiinfo class redundant?

Comment: Yes, unless you have some other intentions. In any way a private class for the above said purpose is completely useless. You can create a member variable and initialize in onCreate

Comment: @CyanidePlague does it help?

Comment: 1. The only purpose of wifiinfo is to hold getmac. And I'm unsure as to where the activity text  is to go. Can it all reside within onCreate?

Comment: @CyanidePlague Updated code.

If this answer helps, please accept my answer

Comment: @CyanidePlague did it helped?

Comment: sorry, I am at school for the better part of today, so I won't be able to test it for a couple of hours, sorry for the delay, will notify you once I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextView to write text and display it on the screen.

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:text="Your text here..."/>
```

If your text line is so long you should write it in res/values/strings.xml:

```
<string name="my_text">This is a very long line text I want to show on screen.</string>
```

And use `android:text="@string/my_text"` to get it in the TextView.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This defiantly does help a bit, however, will that allow me to display a dynamic variable like getmac or will I have to do something extra?